# How is this integral evaluated?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, complex-integration

I simplified an integral to $$\int_{0}^{\infty}{e^{(i\xi-a)x}dx},$$ where $i$ is the imaginary number, $\xi$, and $a\gt0$ are constants. My textbook says this integral evaluates to $$\frac{1}{a-i\xi}$$

I tried doing this $$\int_{0}^{\infty}{e^{(i\xi-a)x}dx}=\int_{0}^{\infty}{e^{-ax}e^{i\xi x}dx}=$$ $$\int_{0}^{\infty}{e^{-ax}[\cos{(\xi x)}+i\sin{(\xi x)}]dx}=$$ $$\int_{0}^{\infty}{e^{-ax}\cos{(\xi x)}dx}+i\int_{0}^{\infty}{e^{-ax}\sin{(\xi x)}dx}=$$ $$\frac{a}{a^2+\xi^2}+\frac{i\xi}{a^2+\xi^2}$$

Does anyone have an idea of how my textbook got $\frac{1}{a-i\xi}$?

Comment: You may simple take $\left(a-i\xi\right)x=u$. The integral still remain from $0$ to $\infty$ by analytic continuation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just multiply the numerator and denominator by conjugate of denominator:

$$\dfrac{1}{a-i\xi}\times\dfrac{a+i\xi}{a+i\xi}$$

$$=\dfrac{a}{a^2+\xi^2} + \dfrac{i\xi}{a^2+\xi^2}$$

Comment: Oh wow. For some reason I didn't consider to combine the fractions and to factor it. Thanks!